# select x where y equals z with in postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

Is there a problem with this syntax?

This is the code (it uses `knex`):

```
getAllSubjectsForATutor(knex, id) {
  console.log("I'm id:", typeof id)
  return knex.from('tutors_subjects').select('subjects_id').where('user_id', id)
  .then(data => {
     console.log("I'm data", data)
   })
}
```

This code logs

```
I'm id: number
I'm data []
```

Despite the data being in the table:

```
tutors_app=# SELECT * FROM tutors_subjects;
 subjects_id | user_id 
-------------+---------
          68 |     146
(1 row)
```

And trying to get the data with `psql` does work:

```
tutors_app=# select subjects_id from tutors_subjects where user_id = 146;
 subjects_id 
-------------
          68
```

Comment: log also, which number it is that is queried. console.log("I'm id:", typeof id, id)

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK but probably some small mistake, I like to use [`.debug(true)`](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-debug) in order to test the query that is built with knex.

```js
function getAllSubjectsForATutor(knex, id) {
  console.log("I'm id:", typeof id);
  return knex
    .from('tutors_subjects')
    .select('subjects_id')
    .where('user_id', id)
    .debug(true)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("I'm data", data);
    });
}
```